# How to use Firebase to upload images in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

I'm following a video tutorial about Nextjs and have seen that the version of Firebase he is using is out of date. I managed to follow all the steps reading the documentation until I got to this point.

Searched here and found some interesting answers on how to achieve the option to upload images to Firebase. [Here the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69719797/how-to-upload-images-to-firebase-web-v9-using-reactjs)

Have tried all solutions and none of them have worked. I get an error message:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)
Bad Request
```

Here the code I'm trying:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { FaceSmileIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import { VideoCameraIcon, PhotoIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { db, storage } from "../firebase";
import { collection, addDoc, serverTimestamp, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useState } from "react";
import {ref, uploadString, getDownloadURL, getStorage} from "firebase/storage";

function InputBox() {

    const {data: session} = useSession();
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const filePickerRef = useRef(null);
    const [imageToPost, setImageToPost] = useState(null);

    const sendPost = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!inputRef.current.value) return;

        const colRef = collection(db, "posts")

        await addDoc(colRef, {
            message: inputRef.current.value,
            name: session.user.name,
            email: session.user.email,
            image: session.user.image,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
        }).then((document) => {
            if(imageToPost) {
                const storageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${document.id}`);
                uploadString(storageRef, imageToPost, "data_url").then((snapshot) => {
                    getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then(URL => {
                        setDoc(doc(db, "posts", document.id), 
                        {imageToPost: URL}, {merge: true}
                        );
                    });
                })
                removeImage();
            }
        })
        inputRef.current.value = "";
    };

    const addImageToPost = (e) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        if(e.target.files[0]) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        }

        reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
            setImageToPost(readerEvent.target.result);
        }
    };

    const removeImage = () => {
        setImageToPost(null);
    };

    return ( <HERE THE REST OF THE CODE>
```

Don't be mad at me. I really tried to do my best to find a solution and to not post here.

Any help will be really appreciated because I can't figure out what is wrong, because as mentioned before I tried all options I found so far.

BTW also tried to assign storage to getStorage() before `` const storageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${document.id}`); ``

Like so:

```
.then((document) => {
   if(imageToPost) {
      const storage = getStorage();
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${document.id}`);

<MORE CODE>
```

And my `firebase.js`file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "APIKEY-HERE",
    authDomain: "AUTHDOMAIN-HERE",
    projectId: "PROJECT-ID-HERE",
    storageBucket: "STORAGE-BUCKET-HERE",
    messagingSenderId: "MESSAGING-SENDER-HERE",
    appId: "APPID-HERE"
  };


  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore(app);

  const storage = getStorage(app);

  export { db, storage };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this worked for me: Firebase: "^9.0.0"

```
addDoc(dbInstance, {
      message: inputRef.current.value,
      name: session?.user?.name,
      email: session?.user?.email,
      image: session?.user?.image,
      timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    }).then((doc) => {
      if (imageToPost) {
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${doc.id}`);

        uploadString(storageRef, imageToPost, "data_url").then((snapshot) => {
          getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
            addDoc(dbInstance, { postImage: url });
          });
        });

        removeImage();
      }
    });

    inputRef.current.value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have used firebase v8.6.3.

```js
const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("colection_name").doc();
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
const uploadTask = storageRef.child('/posts/' + imageToPost.name).put(imageToPost);
console.log(uploadTask)
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
    (snapshot) => {
        // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
        var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
        switch (snapshot.state) {
            case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                console.log('Upload is paused');
                break;
            case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                console.log('Upload is running');
                break;
        }
    },
    (error) => {
        // A full list of error codes is available at
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
        switch (error.code) {
            case 'storage/unauthorized':
                // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                break;
            case 'storage/canceled':
                // User canceled the upload
                break;

            // ...

            case 'storage/unknown':
                // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
                break;
        }
    },
    () => {
        // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
            console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
            docRef.set({
                message: inputRef.current.value,
                name: session.user.name,
                email: session.user.email,
                image: downloadURL,
            });
        });
    }
);
```

If you don't want the upload progress and error then you can get rid of that codes and directly proceed to getDownloadURL.

Comment: Thanks. Should that code replace all the code that is inside `const sendPost = async (e) => {`? Appreciate

Comment: Replace this code from this line const colRef = collection(db, "posts") to removeImage();}})

Comment: Change the collection name and imageToPost with respect to your code.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you but, there is no collection name on my code. And what should be imageToPost.name? There is nothing on my code pointing to this. Again, sorry for take your time. It isn't clear what I have to change from your code to make it work on mine. I just understand to take your code and post it after `const colRef = collection(db, "posts")` until `removeImage();`NOTE I have an if statement (`if(imageToPost)`)where inside is `removeImage()` so to me it makes no sense... Again, sorry to take your time.

Comment: You have mentioned "posts" as your collection name. I hope you're right. No need to change "imageToPost.name". Call this removeImage() after inputRef.current.value = "";

Comment: Don't blindly follow video tutorial. Understand the basics. Happy Learning

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I understand the basics it is just that I see that your code structure is quite different that the one I posted. Really appreciate your effort to help me :)

Comment: I get `TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.firestore is not a function` pointing to `const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("posts").doc();` Imported `import * as firebase from "firebase/app";` but didn't solve it

Comment: Which firebase version you're using?

Comment: If v8 then import like this
import firebase from "firebase/app"
// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/storage"
If you're using v9 then this won't work. You need to change a lot of things according to v9.

Comment: Ok, I'm using firebase version 9.13.0. Need to find another way to achieve it.

Comment: The logic is same in v9 as well. But you should import the v9's method and use according to that. You can refer the firebase docs for that.

Comment: Yes, I'm reading the docs and doing as they say. But still get this error... [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70052479/firebase-storage-an-unknown-error-occurred-please-check-the-error-payload-for] found also other case with the same error